# To which device file is particular storage device mapped?

Tags: linux, devices, storage

I noticed that I never figured this out completely. Linux maps SATA and USB (and many more kind of) storage devices to `/dev/sd[a-z]` device files in the order in which they were "found". Now given that you know that for example a CF flash card is connected to a machine via SATA how do you determine which device file it got? Of course you could just look at `dmesg`, but what if you want to do this programmatically? Parsing it? That's not a good solution. The kernel must provide an API to figure this out and I guess it should be simple. But so far I just haven't found it.

Linux nowadays has a lot of system information written into the filesystem (`sysfs`, `procfs`, `etc`) where you might get the information required to figure out the device file. This however depends on weather the features were enabled at compile time. I am looking for a solution which also works on a minimal kernel, without all the fancy fs things.

Comment: Would UUID mapping constitute 'fancy fs things', because if not that would be a very simple way to go?

Comment: Yes but what if there is no partition yet on the device?

Comment: I guess udev rules is probably the answer..

Answer (score 0):

You either use the persistent names in `/dev/disk/` or higher level software which interacts with udev using the libudev API.